# Google apps script not identifying sheet correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm running a templated google script that constructs an html page with the contents of a google spreadsheet.

When I run the script with the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtDy2rbIwVyldE82MG50SkR3UWYyam5YRVd1ajZlcnc&usp=drive_web#gid=0 everything works fine.

When I run the script with the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0Kd_BKeO9IB-SJvRMhC68q0XMQLrXarVVPlFJa_fMg/edit#gid=0 I get the message that I need to first select an active spreadsheet.

Here is the script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_KEY').getDataRange().getValues();
  return mysheet;
}
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<table>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

It seems that the problem lies in the second spreadsheet.

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reference you are currently assigning to mysheet refers to the document as a whole.  You still need to grab a reference to the sheet that contains the data.

```
function getData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_KEY').getDataRange().getValues();
  var mysheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('NameOfTheSheet');
  return mysheet;
}
```

Comment: It seems that when a spreadsheet contains only a sigle sheet, you don't need to reference the sheet explicitly, if you only want to read its contents. Nevertheless, the script works perfectly for the first spreadsheet, but gives error for the second.

Comment: Does the user the script runs as currently have the first spreadsheet open in their browser but not the second, by any chance?  I've seen similar behavior where a script will work because there is an active session.

Comment: At any rate, I'd check what SpreadsheetApp.openById() is returning.  How is the 'SPREADSHEET_KEY' being set?

Comment: Both sheets were open but only the first runs correctly. I tried to debug but I am getting generic error message "server busy, try again later". The 'SPREADSHEET_KEY' is manually set with values: 0AtDy2rbIwVyldE82MG50SkR3UWYyam5YRVd1ajZlcnc AND 1A0Kd_BKeO9IB-SJvRMhC68q0XMQLrXarVVPlFJa_fMg

Comment: Another difference is the type of url of the 2 spreadsheets. The first url (the one that works perfectly) has the structure: SOME_GOOGLE_PATH/ccc?key=SOME_KEY&usp=drive_web#gid=0. The second url (the one that gives error) has a different structure: SOME_GOOGLE_PATH/SOME_KEY/edit#gid=0. I don't know what kind of structures are available for urls pointing to a google spreadsheet. Why the 2 urls have diferrent structures? Is this the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

use .getActiveSheet()
and the script would be:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_KEY')**.getActiveSheet()**.getDataRange().getValues();
  return mysheet;
}
```